# Cuda global memory load and store

Tags: cuda, gpu

So I am trying to hide global memory latency. Take the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
     x = global_memory[i];

     ... do some computation on x ...

     global_memory[i] = x;
}
```

I wanted to know whether load and store from global memory is blocking, i.e, it doesn't run next line until load or store is finished. For example take the following code:

```
x_next = global_memory[0];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
     x = x_next;
     x_next = global_memory[i+1];

     ... do some computation on x ...

     global_memory[i] = x;
}
```

In this code, x_next is not used until next iteration, so does loading x_next overlap with the computation? In other words, which of the following figures will happen?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I wanted to know whether load and store from global memory is blocking, i.e, it doesn't run next line until load or store is finished.

It is not blocking.  A load operation does not stall a thread.

Note that the compiler will often seek to [unroll loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832429/is-starting-1-thread-per-element-always-optimal-for-data-independent-problems-on/43833050#43833050) (and reorder activity) to enable what you are proposing to do "manually".

But in any event your 2nd realization should allow the load of `gm[1]` to be issued and proceed while the computation being done on `gm[0]` is proceeding.

Global memory stores are also "fire and forget" -- nonblocking.